# Is there a way for adding labels with number of observations per value in violin plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

Image you want to create a violin plot and have data like this:

```
set.seed(123)
Bodytype <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 500, replace = T)
Weight <- rnorm(500,40,1)    
df <- data.frame(Bodytype, Weight)
  ggplot(data = df, 
         aes(x = Bodytype, y = Weight, fill = Bodytype)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(34, 46, 1)) +
  theme_gray()
```

Now I would like to add text label or something for each bodytype at each kg level to see how many observations in each bodytype category that weigh 36 kg, 37kg, etc. Is there are way for achieving this, or am I better off using another plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, here is one:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
summ <- df %>%
  group_by(Bodytype) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), Weight = mean(Weight))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Bodytype, y = Weight, fill = Bodytype)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(34, 46, 1)) +
  theme_gray() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), data = summ)
```

[image: ggplot2 with count labels on the means]

---

Okay, so you want multiple weight counts:

```r
weightcounts <- df %>%
  mutate(Weight = as.integer(round(Weight, 0))) %>%
  group_by(Bodytype, Weight) %>%
  count()
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Bodytype, y = Weight, fill = Bodytype)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(34, 46, 1)) +
  theme_gray() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), data = weightcounts)
```

[image: second ggplot2, with per-weight-counts]

Either way, the premise is that you can generate a summary frame with the associated labels you need, and then add `geom_text` (or `geom_label`) with the new dataset as an argument.

Comment: Thank you, sorry if I was unclear, but I was thinking multiple labels. So there would be one label for bodytype A that weighs 38 kg, one for bodytype B that weighs 39 kg, etc. It might be messy, but I would like to know whether it works or not.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking round. Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another way computing labels outside in `base R`:

```
set.seed(123)
Bodytype <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 500, replace = T)
Weight <- rnorm(500,40,1)    
df <- data.frame(Bodytype, Weight)
#Labels
df$i <- 1
labs <- aggregate(i~Bodytype,df,sum)
labs$Weight<-NA
#Plot
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = Bodytype, y = Weight, fill = Bodytype)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "count", trim = F, adjust = 0.75) +
  geom_text(data=labs,aes(x=Bodytype,y=45,label=i))
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(34, 46, 1)) +
  theme_gray()
```

Output:

[image]